# Problem in solving a system of three differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

A set of three differential equations is described as

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\ \begin{pmatrix}
X(t)\\
Y(t)\\
Z(t)
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
                  -a-bS  & -ibD   &0\\
                    -ibD  & -a+bS & C\\
                        0 & -C & -2a
                 \end{pmatrix}
                            \begin{pmatrix}
                              X(t)\\Y(t)\\Z(t)
                               \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0\\ -2b \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Here, $a,b,C,D$ and $S$ are independent of $t$. How can one approach to solve these equations with $general$ initial conditons $X(0)=X_0$, $Y(0)=Y_0$ and $Z(0)=Z_0$?

Comment: In what way are these differential equations?

Comment: @PaulChilds, thanks. Missed that d/dt on the left.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a linear ODE-system

$$\dot{X} = AX + b,$$

(with $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n},\ X,b \in \mathbb{C}^n$) it is a common strategy to look first at the associated homogenous system

$$\dot{X} = AX.$$

You can make an ansatz for the general solution in form of

$$X_{\text{hom}} = \mathrm e^{tA} C,$$

whereby $C \in \mathbb{C}^n$. For computing $\mathrm e^{tA}$, transform $A$ in Jordan canonical form

$$A = P^{-1} J P,$$

and note that every $J$ can be uniquely written as a sum of a diagonal matrix $D$ and a nilpotent matrix $N$:

$$ J = D + N.$$

Since $D$ and $N$ commute, one can easily show

$$\mathrm e^{tA} = P^{-1} \mathrm{e}^{tD} \mathrm{e}^{tN} P,$$

which can be calculated.

Now, for the inhomogeneous system one shows with variation of constants

$$\dot{C} = (\mathrm e^{tA})^{-1} b,$$

so

$$ C = \int (\mathrm e^{tA})^{-1} b + K) \ \mathrm d t,$$

whereby $K \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$. Now

$$X = \mathrm e^{tA} \left (\int (\mathrm e^{tA})^{-1} b + K) \ \mathrm d t\right).$$

You now can plug in the initial values in order to get $K$.

Comment: thanks. But it looks too formal. Could you work out a couple of steps?

Comment: @TobiasFritzn have you tried to apply Jan's method? Show us your attempts first